# Submit dynamically created input from Angular to PHP Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to create an invoice form, which can make all the necessary calculations like subtotal, tax total by itself .

Hitting the submit button should submit all values and the dynamically created items to a PHP page, which will insert these values (written by the user, or calculated by angularjs) to the appropriate SQL table/column as I wish.

Based on this [project](https://github.com/metaware/angular-invoicing) , I added this javascript code.

```
function PhpCtrl($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
var method = 'POST';
var url = 'added.php';
$scope.codeStatus = "";
$scope.add = function() {
var FormData = {};
$http({
  method: method,
  url: url,
  data: FormData,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  cache: $templateCache
}).
success(function(response) {
    $scope.codeStatus = response.data;
}).
error(function(response) {
    $scope.codeStatus = response || "Request failed";
});
return false;
};
}
```

Can anyone help me how to store all the dynamically created items, along with their values, in order to submit them to a php page ?

Comment: Just use `var FormData = $('#formId').serialize()`. I hope all the "dynamically created items" you mean will be added as HTML elements inside the `<form/>` tag. If you have any variables not inside `<form/>`, add them to the variable like `FormData += '&newValue=123&otherVal=kitty';`.

Comment: You can use the `FormData` object to create the objects you want to submit to the server. But here, you are submitting an empty form.

Comment: Hello cackharot, sadly your solution is not working, Chrome/IE 11 cannot even see the variables when I hit the submit button. As far as the "dynamically created items", please have a look at this [link](https://github.com/metaware/angular-invoicing/blob/master/index.html) page, at lines 78 thru 85. I am using this project to create my invoice form, so the logic is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `FormData` to be submitted dynamically using plain javascript like this:

```
var fd = new FormData();

fd.append("fieldName", valueToSubmit);
fd.append("arrayField[]",[1,2,3]); //you can even post array data
```

The you push `fd` to the server:

```
var uri = "added.php";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST",uri,true);
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200){
        //do something with returned data
    }
};
fd.append("img_file",blob_to_upload);// you can even upload a file
fd.append("user_id",data);
fd.append("category_id",category_id);
xhr.send(fd);
```